# How to alert starting and ending dates of next week

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to alert starting and ending dates of next week

```
var weekCount = 0;
$(".week-next").live('click',function(){
var weekdate = new Date();
var fromweek = weekdate.setTime(weekdate.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var toweek = weekdate.setTime(weekdate.getTime() - (weekdate.getDay() ? weekdate.getDay() : 7) + weekCount * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var prevweekstart = new Date(fromweek);
var prevweekends = new Date(toweek);
prevweekstart = prevweekstart.toLocaleString(),
prevweekends = prevweekends.toLocaleString(),
between = [];
alert(prevweekends);
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WGXxn/8/ check this

Comment: why do you need weekcount flag?

Answer (score 0):

If you weekCount is increasing then keep it default as 1 . You need to store current time plus next week time in a variable named here ( curr ) and use it accordingly .

Here + 6 is used to get Date of friday

```
var weekcount = 1;
$(".week-next").live('click',function(){
    var weekdate = new Date();
    var curr = new Date(weekdate.getTime() + ( ( 7 * weekcount)  * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );

    var fromweek = weekdate.setTime(weekdate.getTime() +  (( 7 * weekcount)  * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );

    var toweek = weekdate.setTime( (curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() )  + 6);

    toweek = curr.setDate(toweek);

    var prevweekstart = new Date(fromweek);
    var prevweekends = new Date(toweek);

    console.log(prevweekstart);
    console.log(prevweekends);

});
```